# I have troubles extracting a particular string within a text I extracted from a pdf with R base

Tags: r, regex

I extract text from some .pdf files. For each resulting text, I want to extract a string who appears after a sentence, followed by \n and any number of spaces.

I tried the following.

```
texte<-"What I don't want\n       WHATIWANT\n OtherStuff I don't want \n I don't want this either."
regex<-"(?<=\\n\\s+)\\w"

debut<-gregexpr(regex,texte)
debut
```

I get an invalid regular expression error. I tried with or without perl=TRUE.

My logic was : first, look backward if you have something like a \n and as many spaces as you want,
if so, look if it's a word, if so give me its position.

Comment: If you have found an answer that works for you, please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the error because neither base TRE regex engine, nor PCRE support variable width patterns inside lookbehinds.

Here, since you are using a positive lookbehind and the matches are not expected to be overlapping, you may use another construct, `\K`:

```r
texte<-"What I don't want\n       WHATIWANT\n OtherStuff I don't want \n I don't want this either."
regex<-"\\n\\s+\\K\\w"
debut<-gregexpr(regex,texte, perl=TRUE)
debut
```

Here

- `\n` - a newline
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `\K` - omit the text matched so far (see [*Keep The Text Matched So Far out of The Overall Regex Match*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html))
- `\w` - a word char.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VQj3Cs/1).

Comment: Thank you very much @Wiktor Sribizew. I spent half a day before I dared to ask...

Comment: Thank you, I'm sorry I reacted so late, I didn't see the notification. I didn't know `\K`, I'll try to use it.

Comment: I didn't tick the mark because I'm not perfectly done yet. I tried to build from your comment but still haven't managed to get the perfect string. Also, I will modify the question and add a space in what I'm trying to grab like texte<-"What I don't want\n       WHATIWANT\n OtherStuff I don't want \n I don't want this either."

Comment: @MatthieuGousseff What is your expected output and why? The `" WHATIWANT"` string? Because it is the first match after a line break? My answer was based on your code, but I can adjust if your pattern (or match) requirements are not exactly those coded inside your code. Maybe all you need is `regmatches(texte, regexpr("\\n\\s+\\K.+",texte, perl=TRUE))`? See [this R demo](https://ideone.com/kByXq4).

Comment: Thank you. Thank you very much, this works well. I'm very sorry I take so long to answer. For some reason I don't see the notifications, so I only realize long after that I had an answer. Your answer is exactly what I need, I ticked it.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**
 A somewhat "naive" approach to get the desired string (if that's your goal), first `strsplit`ing, then searching for two or more spaces at the beginning of the sentence.

```
spl <- strsplit(texte, "\n")[[1]]

spl[grepl("^ {2,}", spl)]
[1] "       WHATIWANT"
```

Comment: Thanks, but the fact there is no space in WHATIWANT is random. Sorry for the late comment, Didn't see the notification

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest following regex `/[^\n]+\n\s*([^\n]+).+/gms`

I have used flags:

- `g` - don't return after first match
- `s` - dot matches newline
- `m` - ^ and $ match start/end of line

Pattern explanation:

`[^\n]+` - match anything except newline, one ore more times

`\s*` - match zero or more whitespaces

`(...)` capturing group

Your desired value/text will be captured in first group.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QpMY3Z/1)